# Shared file view - access control

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, acl, shared-memory

I want to know is it possible to set access control over shared file view, so only processes started by my application can access it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CreateFileMapping` to create an unnamed file mapping with an inheritable handle.

Child processes will inherit the handle, so they can create a view on the file.  Other processes won't have any means of accessing the mapping.